# Django: 500 internal server error with Passenger on Dreamhost

Tags: django, passenger, wsgi, dreamhost

I have a little issue here. I'm building a project in django on dreamhost (shared hosting). Everything is ok when i'm in debug mode and when i use the built-in server, but when i'm trying to switch to prod i get a 500 internal server error. I searched for the solution in every dark room on the internet but still didn't find it.

So, here is my setup :

**my folders :**

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/
/home/user/project/
/home/user/project/sqlite.db
/home/user/project/project/settings.py
/home/user/example.com/project (a symlink to /home/user/project)
/home/user/example.com/passenger_wsgi.py
/home/user/example.com/public/
```

**my passenger_wsgi.py :**

```
import sys, os

INTERP = "/home/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python"
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.append('/home/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/home/user/example.com')
sys.path.append('/home/user/example.com/project')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this ?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention, i installed python 3 and django 1.5 cuz the default versions in DH are too old.

Comment: Have you checked the actual error being thrown in your server logs?

Comment: yep
[Sat Apr 20 05:59:26 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html

Comment: Hmm thats pretty broad, tried these yet? https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: i don't have control on the machine, it's a shared hosting. I can't for example, have access to the Apache logs, or even the httpd.conf. Saying that, what should i try exactly in these FAQ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directory `/home/user/example.com` you need to add a symlink to your database file too.

Also:

- You only need to append `/home/user/example.com/project` to the path. The other two are not necessary, though they should not cause problems.
- Instead of hardcoding the path `/home/user/example.com/project` you can use `os.getcwd()`:

  ```
  sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'project'))
  ```

After you make changes to this file or other files in your project, don't forget to do `touch tmp/restart.txt` to notify Passenger.

By the way, at the moment Django works with Python versions 2.6.5 to 2.7 with experimental support for 3.2 and 3.3. According to the [Python wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python) on DreamHost, most servers should be using Python 2.6.6 as of February 2012, except *some* servers. Check your version of Python with `python --version` and if it's not 2.6.6 then you can ask the support team to upgrade it on your server.

I tried using Django with Python 3.2 or 3.3 on DreamHost but it's problematic. It doesn't work with 3.2 because the `mod_wsgi` module of Apache does not seem to work with this version at the moment. It could work if you install it from source, but being a shared hosting, we don't have control over that. I don't know for sure but if `mod_wsgi` doesn't work with 3.2 then it won't work with 3.3 either. So I think it's best to stick to a supported version of 2.x version if you want to use Django on Dreamhost.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work too. Maybe I should rollback to django 1.4

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaand it worked ! My server has Python 2.6.6 so i just created a new virtualenv with it, moved my project, changed the INTERP path in passenger to python 2.6.6, restarted DH, and it finally worked. Thanks a lot Janos, this really helped me because i thought the problem was on the passenger side and i would never have thought about switching to another python version.